# Вернуть объект с информацией в put методе REST сервиса

Tags: java, spring, rest, put

Мне нужно чтобы при ошибке в запросе на PUT методе возвращались ошибки.
Метод PUT

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/put", method = RequestMethod.PUT,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
            produces = "application/xml")
    public ValifInfo putSpSaveDataToNewStructure(@RequestBody String request) {
        //логика
        ValifInfo valifInfo;    
        /**
         * Валидация
         */
        ValidationFromRestClient validationFromRestClient = new ValidationFromRestClient();
        valifInfo = validationFromRestClient.validmessagesRest(полученный объект из request);

        //логика

        return valifInfo; // приходит нормально заполненный объект
    }
```

класс объекта valifInfo

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "valifInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ValifInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    public StatusValid status;
    @XmlElement(name = "listWarnings")
    public List<String> listWarnings;
    @XmlElement(name = "listErrors")
    public List<String> listErrors;
    @XmlElement(name = "messageInfo")
    public String messageInfo;

    public ValifInfo(StatusValid status, List<String> listWarnings, List<String> listErrors) {
        this.status = status;
        this.listWarnings = listWarnings;
        this.listErrors = listErrors;
    }

    public ValifInfo(StatusValid status, List<String> listWarnings, List<String> listErrors, String messageInfo) {
        this.status = status;
        this.listWarnings = listWarnings;
        this.listErrors = listErrors;
        this.messageInfo = messageInfo;
    }

    public ValifInfo(StatusValid status, String messageInfo) {
        this.status = status;
        this.messageInfo = messageInfo;
    }

    public ValifInfo() {
    }
    public StatusValid getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(StatusValid status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public List<String> getListWarnings() {
        return listWarnings;
    }
    public void setListWarnings(List<String> listWarnings) {
        this.listWarnings = listWarnings;
    }
    public List<String> getListErrors() {
        return listErrors;
    }
    public void setListErrors(List<String> listErrors) {
        this.listErrors = listErrors;
    }
}
```

StatusValid - это простой enum

```
public enum StatusValid {
    OK, ERROR
}
```

собственно, после запроса выходит 404 Not Found.

причем в return valifInfo; приходит не null а заполненный объект

Answer (score 0):

Если весь контроллер не отмечен аннотацией `@RestController`, то для того, что бы сообщить Spring-у, что Вы хотите вернуть некий объект из метода контроллера, на этом самом методе надо навесит аннотацию `@ResponseBody`. Это раз. используйте предоставляемые Spring-ом инструменты валидации входных данных. Для этого Вам необходимо описать класс валидатора, реализующего интерфейс `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. Забиндить его в контроллере как валидатор, добавив в контроллер подобный метод:

```
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());
    }
```

И в конце пометить тело запроса, приходящего в Ваш метод аннотацией `@Valid`

```
public ValifInfo putSpSaveDataToNewStructure(@Valid @RequestBody String request)
```

Подробнее расписано [в документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation)